# Scaling nginx beyond 45k connections

Tags: nginx

I have a situation that means my nginx server has many long running open connections, however after a certain amount of connections it starts throwing an error 'Cannot assign requested address for upstream'.

I've already gone ahead and increased the underlying system limits to the maximum (increasing open file limits, usable port ranges etc), and in terms of CPU/RAM the system is performing absolutely fine, it seems like the bottleneck is just the number of open connections/ports.

Is there really no way to have a **single** nginx server handle say 100k, or 200k concurrent open connections? I know more machines can be added to the equation, but then that disrupts things such as nginx rate limiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you quoted indicates that the problem is not with the number of incoming connections, but the number of *outgoing* connections, from nginx to your backend web application.

You will have done something like this somewhere in your configuration:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
```

Remember that a TCP connection is uniquely identified by source address and port and destination address and port. In this case it appears you have run out of source port numbers to make unique connections.

The obvious immediate fix is to switch to UNIX domain sockets. Your application must also listen on a UNIX domain socket. You might also need to arrange to have nginx's number of open files limit raised (e.g. raise `LimitNOFILE=` in its systemd unit) as well as that of your web app. The number of connections you can make this way is essentially unlimited.

```
proxy_pass unix:/run/myapp/myapp.sock;
```

A less obvious fix, if you can't make your app use UNIX domain sockets, is to have your web app listen on more than one address/port pair, and to have nginx rotate between them. This will double the number of connections you can make. If your web app already listens for both IPv4 and IPv6 connections, then a very quick and cheap fix is to have nginx alternate between them. You could also modify your app to listen on multiple ports.

```
upstream myapp {
   server 127.0.0.1:8000;
   server [::1]:8000;
}
```

or

```
upstream myapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    server 127.0.0.1:8002;
}
```

Then

```
proxy_pass http://myapp;
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional information and clarification about this issue, would enabling keepalive for the upstream also help significantly here? As for running via a unix socket, I'd need to check to see if this is supported with elixir/phoenix/cowboy - if not I'll also try out the cheap fix you mentioned - thanks!

Comment: @Ash I wouldn't expect any benefit to keepalive on the upstream unless your connections are short-lived. If they're long running as you say, then there's no point. As for Phoenix on UNIX sockets, it's apparently possible but poorly documented. I was able to find [this forum post](https://elixirforum.com/t/running-phoenix-on-a-unix-socket/9703) about it.

Comment: I found it too -thanks! It looks like things may be difficult, as socket approach relies on nginx being on the same host as the upstream, right? Similarly, the upstream currently can't be parellised across multiple machines or run on multiple ports, which may simply mean the upsteam can only use a single private IP / single port.

Comment: @Ash You could run multiple copies of your app on multiple machines, if you've designed it to support [scaling out](https://12factor.net/concurrency). You probably don't want to rely on a single monolithic server anyway.

Comment: Yeah that would also work. I'm wondering - if nginx was scaled horizontally, e.g. across 2 hosts, but both pointed to the same single upstream on another host, would this also work? (If I could 'accept' losing rate limiting / needing to use another solution for it).

Comment: @Ash Yes, that would work too, but it would probably be a waste as nginx itself is probably not a bottleneck. Though eventually you'll probably have to anyway. So you should have that capability.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Every machine is limited by the number of available sockets in the underlying network and the tcp/up uses a 2-byte word to define the socket number of the connection. So, there is a physical limitation of 65536 number of connections.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much, I just wondered what the go to solution is when stateful things exist within nginx e.g. rate limiting, which can't be scaled horizontally